# How to execute sqoop commands using the sqoop api?

Tags: java, sqoop

I know how to executed import, import-all-tables and other commands from the command line.

Is there a Java API for sqoop 1.4.2 such that I could excecute those commands directly from the command line? And if yes, how?

A link to the sqoop Java docs or a simple example would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're asking for Java API so that you can start Sqoop programically and not from the command line. I'm afraid that Sqoop 1 do not have such official API.

Some of the users are directly calling Sqoop.run() [1] in order to start Sqoop from within Java. However such invocation is not supported and have it's limitations, for example Hive import do not seem to be working and Sqoop code isn't generally thread safe [2].

Jarcec

Links:

1: https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/Sqoop.java#L120

2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-477